# ListBox without compression when scrolling

Tags: .net, silverlight, listbox, windows-phone

I need a ListBox without any compressions when user scrolls. 
How I can do it?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I don't think you can disable it. Why does it bother you? It is part of the platform.

Comment: Because I need. I use this control in game-like application and this animation is unnecessary.

Comment: If you don't need scrolling inertia, you can emulate scrolling pretty easily yourself by handling manipulation and adjusting transforms

Comment: I need inertia, but thx for comment. I did it already and it works.